Passing Observables from Child components to ancestors or distant components
I have some serious trouble handling observables in angular (sap composable storefront), that I want to acess from another component. I never seem to get them up to date.
CURRENT STATE
I have cart page with Cart-Items and each Item is fetching it's own Availability Status by some special http-request. While Fetching the Data, a Loading icon Shows.
So Each CartItemComponent-Instance has its "availability$"-Observable (and I want it seperated from the rest of the item object, since I want all other item Data displayed while Availability is beging requested meanwhile. The Availability-Status is also refetched once e.g. the quantity counter is changed.
THE REQUIREMENT
Outside the "CartListComponent" (which holds the Array of CartItemComponents) there is CheckoutButtonComponent, that needs to get an ulttimate summary of the entire CartItems availabilities. If one of the Cart Items is not available, then the checkoutbutton must be disabled.
FAILED APPROACHES SO FAR
I tried the easy way and simply reiterated all cartItems in the CheckoutButtonComponent and and got all the availabilities, but this means sending each request twice.
I would rather want to make use of the already received responses from the CartListComponent, but this is where things get complicated.
First I tried handling this with BehaviorSubject, but adding an array of Observables to a Subject looked very unusual and I had trouble accessing the data.
Then I tried applying a @ViewChildren-Marker on the CartItems, and called it within the "onChanges"-Lifecycle Hook of "CartListComponent", but the "availability$"-Observable is never up to date at that point - it's always null since it is still being fetched by the time I try to work with it.
export class CartItemListComponent{
    cartItems: Item[];
   @ViewChildren('entryList') entryList: QueryList<CartItemComponent>;

   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (changes.items && this.entryList) {
            const availabilities$: Observable<string>[] = this.entryList.map(entry => entry.availability$);
            //Note that "availability$ is always null at this point
        }
    }
}


<ng-container *ngFor="let item of cartItems;">
    <cart-item #entryList [item]="item">
    </cart-item>
</ng-container>


export class CartItemComponent{
  @Input() item: OrderEntry;

  availability$: Observable<string> = availabilityService.get(this.item);

}

Currently I'm not even sure if this approach is even going to work, because ultimately I need that data within a distant component, that is not a child component of CartListComponent, but I don't want to retrigger the same requests.
How would you solve this dilemma?

You can use ngAfterViewInit and listen for observable emits, only in this hook, viewchild will get processed and available if static is false (default).
Then use combineLatest to trigger each time an emission happens, then use debounceTime to reduce the number of times the button is calculated. Only taking the latest value using debounce.
export class CartItemListComponent{
   private sub: Subscription = new Subscription();
   buttonDisabled = false;
   cartItems: Item[];
   @ViewChildren('entryList') entryList: QueryList<CartItemComponent>;

   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (changes.items && this.entryList) {
            const availabilities$: Observable<string>[] = this.entryList.map(entry => entry.availability$);
            //Note that "availability$ is always null at this point
            this.sub.add(
            combineLatest(availabilities$).pipe(
                debounceTime(250),
                tap((arr: Array<string>) => {
                  this.buttonDisabled = arr.every(x => x); // check if all are true
                }),
            ).subscribe()
            );
        }
    }

   ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
   }
}


Unfortunately that doesn't work. Firstly using switchMap without a return parameter doesnt compile, and the new observable is not subscribed to (the sub.add doesnt make sense so far), but if I do so, the value emitted there is not updated in the html.
Assigning this combinelatest operation to a new observable leads to the same issue I had before. The values are not updated in time. Once I remove an entry, I still hold the previews array of values.

but using the "debounce" actually helped (using it in a "onChanges"-Lifecyclehook tough).

@SergejBjakow try after view init, it's intended to be used there

@SergejBjakow sorry use tap instead this should work great

AFterViewInit does not work for me, since it is not triggered again once I perform changes to the entryList. "OnChanges" is lifecycle hook that does the job.
But Your post helped me by drawing my attention to the "debounceMethod" which seemed to be the crucial part, to get this thing working

But I'm really curious if there would also be a way without relying on some random period of time

@SergejBjakow I just added that for performance reasons, else that array every method will get call everytime, but if there is no performance impact, feel free to get rid of debounce time, or reducing the time to 10 or 100, that will give instant update of the variable
